# How to a set a cookie and use it withou reloading the page?

Tags: php, cookies

Using apache and php, it is impossible to set a cookie using `setcookie()` function and use the same cookie without reloading the page, as stated in https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php:

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE array.

Is there any way to overcome this issue and use the cookie without reloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found a way to overcome this issue.

```
setcookie('cookie_id', $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 13));
$_COOKIE['cookie_id'] = $cookie_value;
```

Maybe there another way to do this, but this solved my problem.

Comment: Thats pretty much what I do ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  ... you can write a mini function that does both of those whenever you wish to set a cookie, to make it 1 less line of code if you do this in multiple places.

Comment: Thank you so much, I read so many resources that are complaex and some of them did not work correctly. This 2 line code saves my huge time. Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is not an issue, it's the way Cookies work.

> Cookies are set using the Set-Cookie HTTP header, sent in an HTTP response from the web server.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Implementation

Let's say you call the index.php and set a cookie in there, why isn't it available in the same PHP script? Since the server is sending the header and body at once, so there is no "hey, send this cookie header first and then do other stuff". The cookie is received by the client when the PHP script has ended and sent it's header + body.